# Splitting out 3 or more Arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

Martin Odersky gives this example to split out an array into 2 collections:

```
val people: Array[Person]
val (minors, adults) = people partition (_.age < 18)

class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

What is the best way to split out into 3 or more arrays:

val (minors, adults, seniors) = people partition?? x < 18, 18 < x < 65, x > 65 // ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing that with a one-liner would be probably less pretty.

```
val (minors, older) = people partition {_.age < 18}
val (adults, seniors) = older partition {_.age < 65}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def multiPartition[T: Manifest](xs: Traversable[T])(fs: T => Boolean *) = {
  val builders = Vector.fill(fs.length)(ArrayBuffer.empty[T])
  for (e <- xs) {
    val i = fs.indexWhere(f => f(e))
    if (i >= 0) builders(i) += e
  }
  builders.map(_.toArray)    
}
```

Example usage would be:

```
val Seq(minors, adults, seniors) = 
    multiPartition(people)(_.age < 18, _.age < 65, _ => true)
```

so each term in the second arg list is a "bucket", with `_ => true` being "everything else".

This returns Arrays. I made a very similar version that spits out your original collection type [here](https://gist.github.com/3080119), although I don't know how to get that to work for Arrays as well.

Comment: It is easier for me to reason about a generic multiPartition as applying mutually exclusive filter functions to a collection which can be implemented as `for(f <- fs) yield xs.filter(f)`. It's slower since the collection xs is filtered for each filter fs though.

Comment: @Brian That would work differently to the above if the conditions are overlapping. My implementation adds the element to the first bucket that satisfies the condition. How it *should* work is debatable, but I chose this way because to me "partition" suggests a set of elements split up, and not duplicated. It also has the advantage that you can easily have an identity bucket for "everything else" than defining an extra function as a negation of all the others.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I noted the filters have to be mutually exclusive or there is overlap.

Answer (score 2):

This will return a Tuple3 like you note in the question of minors, adults, and seniors. There is probably a more efficient and general approach though.

`Tuple3(people.filter(_.age < 18), people.filter(p => p.age > 18 && p.age < 65), people.filter(_.age > 65))`

Answer (score 2):

You may use the method groupBy:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val people = Array(Person("A",1),Person("B",2),Person("C",14),Person("D",19),Person("E",70))

def typeByAge(p: Person): String = 
  if(p.age < 4) "BABY"
  else if(p.age < 18) "MINOR"
  else if(p.age < 65) "ADULT"
  else "OLD"

val g = people groupBy typeByAge

val (babys,minors,adults,olds) = (g("BABY"),g("MINOR"),g("ADULT"),g("OLD"))
```